# A combinatorics problem in IWYMIC 2019

Tags: combinatorics

There are 10 identical red balls, 15 identical black balls, 20 identical white balls. We want to distribute all the balls to 2 boys and a girl. Each boy must receive at least 2 balls of each color and the girl must receive at least 3 balls of each color. What is the total number of different ways to distribute the balls to those three children?

Comment: [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is a common and useful technique for such problems.  In some cases (as here), you must first dole out some items before you can apply stars and bars.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Distribute the balls separately.

For red balls, you first give each of the boys one red ball and give the girl two red balls. You are left with $6$ red balls.

Put them in a row, so that there are $5$ gaps between them. Put two separators in the $5$ gaps will separate them into three parts, each with at least one ball. Distribute them to the three kids and you are done.

This means the number of ways to distribute the red balls is just the number of ways to choose $2$ gaps from $5$, i.e. $C_{5}^{2} = 10$ ways.

Same procedure for the other two colors, and you get $C_{10}^2 = 45$ and $C_{15}^2 = 105$ respectively.

Finally, multiply the three and the final answer is $10\times 45\times 105 = 47250$.

Comment: Your solution is nice. I understanded that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. You can support the answer by upvoting and/or accepting it.